# Thin Film Interference Maxima Calculation

Tags: visible-light, interference

**I would like to calculate for which thickness, d, I have maxima.**

The Set-Up:
I have a laser of wavelength 300nm that shines with normal incidence onto the layers. Now, I would like to calculate for which thicknesses ***d*** I have maximas for the thin film interference.

[image]

How can I do it ?